# Insert guest Edition qemu/kvm | linux host, windows guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, guest-os

It always takes me a lot of time to find the qemu guest edition for windows.
Simmilar as in virtual box, where it is called "insert Guest edition" there is a feature for qemu windows hosts. You just need to get the signed iso.

I'm going to collect here ways in how to retrieve that.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what's the question again, and how does it relate to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Most promising page is that one:

https://github.com/virtio-win/virtio-win-pkg-scripts/blob/master/README.md

You'll find the tutorial here:

https://linuxhint.com/install_virtio_drivers_kvm_qemu_windows_vm/

It refers to a outdated Fedorra page, where Fedorra tells you, that they have issues with signing the drivers for windows.

You can find the link to the masterpage regarding kvm/qemu here:
https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers